# Which are the proprietary and paid games for linux do you know - Commercial games

Tags: games, proprietary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What native games are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6586/what-native-games-are-available)

I know only 2 games... quake 4 and Doom 3
Have any others you know ?
Paid/proprietary games... (commercial games )
These type of games i would like to know...

Comment: There are several proprietary games and a link to a site with about 100 of them posted in [this community wiki](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6586/what-native-games-are-available).

Comment: As you have indicated you mean commercial games, you should reword this, proprietary will be read as native, i.e. 'for ubuntu only'

Comment: "proprietary" is the contrary of "free" only regarding "availability of source code". It doesn't necessary mean that the software must be paid. There are proprietary software that you don't need to pay for using. Look at Internet Explorer for instance :)

Comment: This question is just a localized version of [What native games are available?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6586/what-native-games-are-available)

Comment: you all don't understand me, I want a "specific answer" . COMMERCIAL GAMES (games i have to pay , games that are propertary)

Comment: I think we did understand... Still I insist: "proprietary" doesn't mean "must pay for it". So ok, you want commercial games... Actually, if you follow the "duplicate" link, you'll find both commercial and non-commercial games... Doesn't it answer your question ?