# How to Install and run Greedy Car Thieves?

Tags: games, software-installation

I heard about the game "Greedy Car Thieves"  which is inspired by "GTA2".
How to install it? I'd also like to have the game on my launcher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the official download page](http://gct-game.net/?page=download):

> #### Dependencies (debian/ubuntu package names):
>
> Nvidia-Cg-Toolkit (nvidia-cg-toolkit)
>   WxWidgets GTK 2.8 (libwxgtk2.8-dev)
>   SDL_image (libsdl-image1.2)
>   SDL_ttf (libsdl-ttf2.0-0)
>
> ---
>
> Unpack the archive and run ./gct-game-startup from a proper directory.
>
> Run install.sh as a root (e.g. sudo ./install.sh) to install the game. Afterwards, every user will be able to run gct-game-startup command.
>
> Startup doesn't kill server, so kill it manually if you have to with: killall gct-server
>
> Run ./gct-server for dedicated server. It doesn't need any libraries related to the graphics, so can be run on almost every modern Linux, even without X11.

If the install doesn't add it to the launcher, just do it manually :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that in synaptic package manager the following packages are installed:

   - `nvidia-cg-toolkit`
   - `libwxgtk2.8-dev`
   - `libsdl-image1.2`
   - `libsdl-ttf2.0-0`
2. Download and extract to your home folder (or folder of your choice) one of the following:

   - [For a 32-bit system](http://gct-game.net/?page=may-2011-x86)
   - [For a 64-bit system](http://gct-game.net/?page=may-2011-x86_64)
3. Inside the folder you just extracted (mine was called `GCT-may-2011-linux-x86_64`) there is a file called `install.sh`.Run that file as root in the terminal.

   Note: To run the file as root, in the terminal type `sudo`, and then drag the 'install.sh' file from nautilus onto the terminal window.
4. To play Greedy Car Theves, just run the file `gct-game-startup`, and click the refresh button to see a list of available servers.