# Where can I find websites that list games for Ubuntu?

Tags: games

> **This question is present as a matter of historical interest.  While you are encouraged to help maintain its answers, please understand that "big list" questions are not generally allowed on AskUbuntu and will be closed per the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask).**

Not all games are in the software center and I don't know where to find others.

Please help me find websites online that list games for Ubuntu. I don't mind if they are free or not.

*I don't want recommendations of individual games - just link me to the lists/websites that surely must exist already somewhere...*

PlayOnLinux isn't a site where I can find games, it's a tool for installing windows based games in Ubuntu. I don't want the source code of a game either.

I like the answers from [Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39382/where-can-i-find-websites-that-list-games-for-ubuntu/46893#46893), [Alan](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39382/where-can-i-find-websites-that-list-games-for-ubuntu/39395#39395) and [CYREX](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39382/where-can-i-find-websites-that-list-games-for-ubuntu/39393#39393) more of those please.

Comment: I dont want games, I want sources where I can find games, not the same.

Comment: That article - is a source :)

Comment: yes, put it as an answer. Good point. more?

Comment: @pydave add it as an answer, not a comment! :)

Comment: As a list question, this is off-topic, [as per the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask), specifically the part where it says `To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …

every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”`

Comment: @jrg I want to hack the FAQ now and remove those lines! that is one of the few reasons I go to this site. who came up with that idea?

Comment: @Alvar: Moved it to the top of my old answer.

Comment: Games on Arch Linux : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/List_of_games , I believe, all of them are available for Ubuntu too ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The webpage [playdeb.net](http://www.playdeb.net) offers a good list of games for Ubuntu. The ppa is found in their website which is http://www.playdeb.net/updates/Ubuntu/11.04#how_to_install

This is the one i use for many games.

For other good sites you can check the following:

- http://www.linuxgames.com/ - News about linux games (Very up to date)
- http://www.happypenguin.org/ - News and more detailed info about games (Also up to date)
- http://www.lgdb.org/ - News about linux games that even include system requirements for them and comments about the game.

Comment: +1. It is a good answer. deb's even include the source ;-)

Answer (score 11):

There's a nice list on this very website: [What native games are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6586/what-native-games-are-available)

Complete in many cases with screenshots and Software Centre links.

Answer (score 10):

This website has a nice list. [Penguspy](http://www.penguspy.com/).

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean or not.

Comment: It's a very good answer! :D I want sources where I can find games so yes that's what I want.

Comment: I just hope rigs of roads is as good as the video tell me! :) very good site :D!

Comment: There are some nice games on there. The non-free games are of great quality too!

Answer (score 4):

I recommend a website called [PlayDeb](http://playdeb.net), it provides a large directory of open-source and freeware games. It also features a comprehensive search tool if you are looking for something specific.

Answer (score 3):

[PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en) allows you to play Windows based games on Ubuntu.  See [here](http://www.playonlinux.com/repository/?cat=1) for a list of Games you can run directly on Linux.

However if you want to compile your own games - then [SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=games&fq%5B%5D=trove:80) is a good place to look

Comment: but you can't get the games in PlayOnLinux you can use it to play games you already have, there for not a source!

Comment: Are you talking about Source Code that you can see and compile?  If so - please edit your question to clarify this.

Comment: No, I want the source of the program like the Apple mac store, or steam for mac.) PlayOnLinux is really great if you have the game which I haven't!

Answer (score 2):

[DotDeb](http://www.dotdeb.com) offers deb packaged games debianized on Ubuntu for Ubuntu and tested on Ubuntu,  Categories inclued: Arcade, MarioLemming, Word Games, Simulation, Strategy and more.  Most of these deb packages are available only on DotDeb and cannot be found in the Ubuntu-Software-Center or anywhere else on the internet, making it a great place to visit for extended software options.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list with DEBs from [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=427205). Some of these will be in USC though.

This is a project on trying to get a database together called [the Linux Gamers' Game List](http://www.icculus.org/lgfaq/gamelist.php). You can even search for non free software and publisher:

[image: im1]

Answer (score 2):

Alright, here are three lists of games:

1. Humble Indie Bundle
2. Software Centre
3. ScummVM

### Humble Indie Bundle

While it's not a very big list, the [Humble Indie Bundle](http://www.humblebundle.com/) often features a short list of (mostly) multiplatform games to buy as a package. It's a pay-what-you-want deal so time is limited, but they have a new deal every year.

### Software Centre

There are games available in the Ubuntu Software Centre. After you [setup PlayDeb](http://www.playdeb.net/updates/Ubuntu/11.04#how_to_install), those games will be available there too.

The main page has a games category:
[image: The software categories in Ubuntu Software Centre]

From there you can pick different categories.

If you pick the "All" category, you'll have a list of games:
[image: The games in the All category]

Some of the titles are for sale. You can view look at these by expanding "Get Software" on the left and selecting "For Purchase". I'm not sure how you can view only the free games. (View > Canonical-Maintained Software removes many free games.)

### ScummVM

In the Software Centre, ScummVM is a great option for adventure games. You can install
Beneath a Steel Sky and Flight of the Amazon Queen for it through the Software Centre (They're classic games that the developer released as freeware.) Additionally, the ScummVM website [has a list](http://www.scummvm.org/downloads/#extras) of more freeware ScummVM games.

Comment: *Not all games are in the software center and I don't know where to find others.*

this suggest that I don't want to be tipped about USC which I already know about.

Comment: @Alvar: Ah, I missed that. Hopefully this is still useful to someone else looking for any list of linux games.

Comment: Also expanded on ScummVM and linked to a list of games for it you can download.