# What web browsers are there for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I was wondering what web browsers exist for Ubuntu; I don't want to use wine. I just want the ones written for Ubuntu.

I've never liked the Ubuntu Software Center because it never has all of the programs that I might want to install and therefore it's not perfect.

I just want a list of all the browsers for Ubuntu and their advantages.

**Example:**

> Firefox: open source, and is pre-installed.

*Please give me only one browser per answer or this will be confusing.*

Comment: This would make a nice community wiki.

Comment: Also it would be good to know what you defined "good at streaming video" as. Do you mean; has implemented flash player in a stable way which contributes to a good user experience and performance when streaming videos? Or do you mean in terms of html5 video streaming?

Comment: I'm assuming that by saying you don't want Google chrome, you also don't want Chrom**ium**? There is some difference between the two, and depending on the reason you don't want Google Chrome, Chromium might work for you. I'm not trying to defensive of Google Chrome, but why do you want an alternative to it?

Comment: @ancide When I use google chrome or firefox the videos are slow and laggy. So I can't watch them in fullscreen, but when I used Opera I had no problems at all! :D
I want a browser that has no problems in streaming flash video.

Comment: @Azendale I normally use Google Chrome at an everyday basis. All browsers aren't good at everything that's why.

Comment: Tested a lot of them and after such periods of trying new stuff I come back to the same conclusion, namely that although there are a number of browsers out there, most of them are not as stable as others. A browser that crashes or crashes even your system now and then should not be considered as a browser nowadays. And most of them (apart from the console-like browsers for aficionados) fail at that simple condition of stability. My opinion is that Firefox rules supreme. With my only 1 GB of ram  it feels light with addons. Secondly Chrome & co, and rarely, Opera. Facts are stronger then fancy.

Comment: @cipricus that's why you have the ability to upvote or downvote an answer, if you don't like the browser, just down vote it, if you like it upvote it. it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 23):

You can open Ubuntu Software Center and search for it. There are a plenty of browsers besides those you mentioned:

Refer this [Wikipedia link for List of Web Browsers for Unix and Unix-like OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers_for_Unix_and_Unix-like_operating_systems) to see some.

And here come two examples:

### [Opera](http://www.opera.com/)

[Clik here for installation Instructions at Ubuntu Community Help Wiki.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OperaBrowser)

[image]

### [Links](http://www.jikos.cz/%7Emikulas/links/) [image: Install links]

[image]

Comment: Not all programs are in the Ubuntu software center.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/39382/where-can-i-find-games-for-ubuntu

Comment: Your Links screenshot should use [this](http://sa.column80.com/?api=28) page :P

Comment: @George Edison: I updated as you suggested. Thank you very much ;-)

Comment: That looks awesome!

Answer (score 18):

### [Midori](http://www.twotoasts.de/index.php?/pages/midori_summary.html) [image: Install midori]

It's is a lightweight web browser.

[image]

Comment: I added some screenshots to give people a better idea of what the browsers are like.

Answer (score 14):

### [Epiphany](http://projects.gnome.org/epiphany/)

It's is a minimal GNOME browser that uses WebKitGTK+. It's package name is [epiphany-browser [image: Install epiphany-browser]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/epiphany-browser).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Epiphany crashed as soon as I started a flash video. FAIL

Comment: @Alvar Well, so much for that! I tried it and it just showed a blank, light grey rectangle. I never used it enough to run into video problems.

Answer (score 14):

### [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/Home)

It's package name is [chromium-browser [image: Install chromium-browser]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/chromium-browser).

[image]

Answer (score 10):

### [links2 [image: Install links2]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/links2)

If you ever end up without a desktop but can get to a command line this browser is what you need.

[image: im1]

It even has a graphics version:

`links2 -g`

Comment: This is the future of browsing, free from any commercials or heavy flash scripts! This is truly awesome, I even managed to send a gmail to a friend with a screenshot of me emailing it! :D

Comment: Btw you don't need the sudo. :)

Comment: @Alvar: for commercials, use adblock and flashblock.

Comment: @eudoxos that has nothing todo with my comment. IF you don't read any heavy scripts then the browsing is actually quite fast...

Comment: @Alvar: nothing to do with your second comment. First one mentions ads and flash scripts (scripts?). For blocking javascript, there is noscript, if that's what you meant.

Comment: you don't even see my point.

Answer (score 9):

### [Rekonq [image: Install rekonq]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/rekonq)

[image]

It's light, somewhat fast, and pretty stable.

Oh, and it **is** in the software centre and the default browser on Kubuntu ;).

Comment: Eh, wasn't the default KDE browser Konquerer?

Comment: @Oxwivi : Eh, didn't that change since forever on Kubuntu? (Which is relevant to Ubuntu).

Comment: Last I tried Kubuntu was at 10.04 and it had Konquerer.

Comment: Just wondering about the *default* part you mentioned.

Comment: @Ward why thank you for calling me a wild donkey.

Answer (score 9):

## [Lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/) [image: Install Lynx]

Lynx is one of the oldest command-line browsers that still exist and work rather well. There really isn't much more to say about it except it's lightweight, easy to use, and does a pretty good job of displaying the DOM via terminal.

```
lynx http://askubuntu.com/
```

[image: Ask Ubuntu via Lynx]

<kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd> Navigate page (jumps between links)

<kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>Return</kbd> Follow link

<kbd>←</kbd> Back in history

<kbd>/</kbd> Search

<kbd>Q</kbd> Quit

<kbd>H</kbd> Help

The rest of the docmentation can be found in the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/lynx) or via the help interface.

Answer (score 8):

## [Konqueror](http://www.konqueror.org/) [image: Install konqueror]

### Description

The layout engine Safari and Chrome use (WebKit) is based on the layout engine Konqueror uses (KHTML).
Konqueror was originally integrated into the KDE desktop as a file manager and default web browser.

### Screenshot

[image: Konqueror screenshot]

Comment: Lole, where did you get ye olde screenshot from?

Comment: @Roland: From the first Google image result for 'konquerer' :)

Comment: I had bad experience with this browser in Lucid and before, links on various websites (including ubuntuforums.org) were cropped (the text next to it slided under the link) and more CSS issues.

Comment: I'll give you an updated screen shot :D!

Comment: @Lek: That's true. I've heard that it has a lot of CSS problems.

Answer (score 8):

### [Arora](http://code.google.com/p/arora/) [image: Install arora]

Arora uses webkit and QT.

[image: Arora Screenshot]

Answer (score 8):

### [Seamonkey](http://www.seamonkey-project.org/) [image: Install seamonkey], (*new repository:*  [image: Install seamonkey via wiki])

You can try the Seamonkey Internet Suite, which bundles a Firefox-based browser, Thunderbird-based mail client, IRC client named Chatzilla, and a web page editor named Composer. Seamonkey is an open source version of the hallowed Netscape Communicator internet suite. One big advantage of using Seamonkey is that if the mail client is already open, the browser will open zero delay. The other advantage is that all your browser, mail client messages and accounts, chat settings, add-ons, and passwords are all in one directory. When you change your computer or upgrade the OS, you just need to copy the Seamonkey profile folder. Almost all Firefox extensions work without any problem.

Seamonkey is available for Windows and Mac also. It can be very useful for Linux users who use multiple operating systems. The profile folder works across platforms. 64-bit Linux users should note that the regular download file will not let flash to run properly. The "unofficial" 64-bit build is usually available in the page under the "Other Systems and Languages" link. It works without a problem in all the Ubuntu installations that I have tried. Installation is simple. Extract the archive in the /opt directory and create a soft link to seamonkey file in /usr/bin. You may want to backup any old `/usr/bin/seamonkey` link that may exist.

This is the modern theme:

[image]

---

Some tweaks to make Seamonkey look and act sleek and fresh:

- Right-click on navigation bar, "Customize": drag the  google etc search space onto the navigation bar (possible remove the old "search" button by dragging it into the Customize Toolbar window; also may remove or add other stuff visible there)
- To make tabs more customizable install [Tab Clicking Options](http://www.binaryturf.com/free-software/tab-clicking-options-for-firefox-4/)
- Support for more addons and plugins on [mozdev.org](http://www.mozdev.org/). (e.g. [context search](http://xsidebar.mozdev.org/modifiedmisc.html#contextsearch))
- There are few themes available, but the default one is decent, and [Kilome](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/seamonkey/addon/kilome/?src=cb-dl-users) has a light fresh look. Also, the new type of firefox themes (formerly called "personas") can be also used to spice up the default theme, and they are very different.

Kilome theme:

[image]

Also:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Beside Firefox, Opera, Chromium and Google Chrome, it is difficult to find a stable and simple Internet Browser. Seamonkey is an exception. In spite of its primitive look it is a very trustworthy parent of Firefox.

Comment: It may be old but there is nothing primitive about it. It has a functional interface that works. That is why Seamonkey users choose it over Firefox or Chrome. If anyone wants the barebones look, they should stick to other browsers.

Comment: i agree!! i only dislike the lack of themes, my eyes heart when i see the "modern" one, but "Kilome" is ok. as for the rest is an awesome browser. what a coincidence: you commented a few minutes after i started using Seamonkey again. i use FF because it works on my computer very well, but i'm thinking using seamonkey with the "openwith" addon of ff so as to launch it with a lot of addons that would not normally use in ff. using multiple profiles in ff can cause problems, as i've learned lately, so seamonke is a solution to what i was asking here: http://askubuntu.com/q/228309/47206

Comment: on a parallel use of Firefox/Seamonkey, see last part of this answer (http://askubuntu.com/a/231014/47206)

Answer (score 7):

The [Amaya Web Browser/Editor](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/) is primarily a WYSIWYG Web editor that also works as a Web browser. It is open source, and from the World Wide Web Consortium, which maintains standards for HTML, XHTML, and so on, so it is particularly good at testing for standards compliance.

[image: Amaya]

Answer (score 6):

[Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome?hl=en), based on the open source Chromium browser.

[image: Screenshot showing Google Chrome, with three open tabs.]

Answer (score 5):

### [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/) [image: Install w3m]

It depends what you require. If you are in the geeky corner, why not try [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/)? It runs in the terminal.

An example:

`w3m example.org`

You can scroll up and down with the arrow keys, or by pressing `C-v` and `M-v`.

[image: w3m - Google]

Comment: haha that's awesome, but not that practical if you want to stream video form like, youtube.

Comment: Yes. It is probably "a little bit" limited for such matters. :)

Comment: w3m is also great for when you need to feed web content into a script but can't be bothered to sort through tabs. w3m + grep = awesomely simple content scraping

Answer (score 4):

### [Dillo](http://www.dillo.org/) [image: Install dillo]

Dillo is a lightweight web browser based on FLTK.

[image: screenshot of dillo from their webpage]

Answer (score 4):

#### [Swiftfox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiftfox)

[image]

> Swiftfox is a web browser based on Mozilla Firefox. It is available for Linux platforms and distributed by Jason Halme.

Answer (score 4):

[Vimprobable](http://www.vimprobable.org/), a lightweight webkit browser that is keyboard driven. Links are activated by a keypress which triggers a "hint" - a number next to each link that is then entered to activate the link.

It is fast, stable and doesn't require the rodent.

[image: Vimprobable]

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for an alternative to Google Chrome because:

- You don't like their policy when it comes to gathering user information
- You don't like the fact that they send you dynamic error pages from their servers instead of serving local error pages
- You want a built-in ad blocker

But you like they way Chrome looks like and how it works, then [SRWare Iron](http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron_download.php) is an alternative for you. It is a fork of Chromium which doesn't send user information to Google or interact with Google in any other way and contains a built-in ad blocker.

- [A list of the diffs between Chrome and Iron](http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron_chrome_vs_iron.php)
- [A list of Iron downloads](http://www.srware.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=2415)
- In case you don't know how to install a .deb on ubuntu, [here's how](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-how-do-i-install-deb-packages/)

Comment: got a lot of bad press though, didn't it?

Comment: I don't know what you are referring to, so please show us what are talking about.

Comment: The main reason for not using it is that it basically is Chromium, with three (already user-configurable) privacy options hardcoded in. I'd rather stay with Chromium, where I get faster security patches and don't have to trust 'SRWare' not to add any malicious code in an update. The bad press was concerning how the author just made it to get the publicity etc. Can't find the link, sorry, I'll have a look later.  But really, why use Iron ON LINUX when you can use Chromium?

Comment: @The Negative Shape: I see. I hope you find the link, it would be interesting to read. I wasn't aware of the privacy options could turn off the functionality making Iron obsolete. So thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Ancide, @The Negative Shape: here is one: [Is Iron a Scam? Yes](http://chromium.hybridsource.org/the-iron-scam). It's out of date now, as it deals with no later than Chromium/Chrome/Iron 4 and now it's up to 11/12/13, but the situation seems to be approximately the same. Except that the options which weren't exposed in the UI - approximately the only justification for Iron, really - are now.

Comment: @Chris Morgan I had no idea, so thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

### [Luakit](http://luakit.org/projects/luakit/) [image: Install luakit]

It is based on webkit. It can be controlled entirely from keyboard and is extensible/configurable with lua!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### [Galeon](http://galeon.sourceforge.net/)

It's stated principles are simplicity and standards compliance.

[image]

Comment: There hasn't been a new release of Galeon since 2006.

Comment: That's almost as old as Netscape! and Netscape is just something you would use in mac os 9, for instance.