# How can I visit external website through ssh forwarding through a single port?

Tags: ssh, remote, port-forwarding, tunnel

I need to ssh into my work computer, and then I need to connect to an external website (hosted entirely at another company) that my work has contracted with using my work machine.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112177/how-do-i-tunnel-and-browse-the-server-webpage-on-my-laptop) says I can **tunnel through a single port** using:

```
ssh -L 8080:server-hostname:80 remote-host
```

Which is ideal because then I don't have to pipe my entire traffic to my work machine. So if the website I need to access with my work machine is at:

http://www.abcde.com/1020-39x/proprietary-documentation-blah

I tried:

ssh -L 8080:http://www.abcde.com/1020-39x/proprietary-documentation-blah:80 me@work

But command returns an error saying `Bad local forwarding specification`

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to get to the website entirely by ssh, or would using a web browser be an option? You can set, for example, Firefox to use an ssh tunnel.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do it this way:

```
ssh -L 8080:www.abcde.com:80 me@work
```

and then connect with your browser to:

http://localhost:8080/1020-39x/proprietary-documentation-blah

to get the content of your remote server on `www.abcde.com`.

Comment: The content is hosted at the client site, which is not part of the internal corporate network. So basically, I'm asking how I can ssh into my corporate machine, then browse to the `www.abcd.com/...` as though I was sitting at my desk and using my web browser on my work machine. I think your answer assumes that the content is hosted directly on the corporate servers, because I'm getting 'the requested URL is invalid` when I try it.

Comment: so for this would be better to use dynamic forwarding (aka SOCKS proxy): `ssh -D 9999 me@work` and then set up your browser to pass data over this proxy, which would allow you to connect directly to the website using the same URL.