# how do I download tv shows, etc.?

Tags: downloads, torrent-client

What do I have to do to download from The Pirate Bay?

I understand utorrent and The Pirate Bay, but can not download movies. I used to be able to do it in Windows.

Please keep explanations simple. I want to watch my tv shows when overseas.

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/q/56300/169736

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you're talking about those german shows that are soo popular under creative commons licence.

Press the Ubuntu logo in unity, then pick the second element in that menu that looks like an A. Type in `Transmission`. If it's in the first row (installed) it's already installed and your magnet links should already work with firefox, or one of the other rows (available) you press it and see info of the program. Press download to get it. It will ask for your password and it will show up in your menu when it's finished.

When installed, it should have given the association with magnet-links so every click on one of those in TPB sends that to Transmission.

Hope it helps and have fun :)