# How to convert the Ubuntu 32bit torrent to an iso

Tags: boot, iso, bittorrent

Last night, we managed to get Linux mint off of my laptop. It had to be formatted through terminal cause nothing else worked. We booted to a Zalman last night and Ubuntu was booting, but it got interrupted. This morning, the Zalman would only boot mint, but we just got that off the laptop. I tried the Ubuntu and even the Windows 10 on it, but neither one of them would boot. I am now on the windows 10 computer in the house, and I am trying to convert a torrent Ubuntu 32bit to an iso and burn it to a DVD. How do I convert a torrent file to an Iso?

Comment: The torrent file is not an Ubuntu image itself.  You can open the torrent file using a torrent client which then downloads the iso image from a peer-to-peer network. It's usually a faster method than direct download.

Comment: You should ask on [superuser](https://superuser.com/) because it's off-topic here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I download torrents?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56300/how-do-i-download-torrents)

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat off-topic, as it is not related directly to Ubuntu, but I'll answer anyway.

You seem to be misunderstanding what a torrent is. A torrent is a file that is used in peer-to-peer connections, it is used to track what files need to be downloaded and what tracker should be used to connect to other peers. The whole point of peer-to-peer connections is that you download files from a large number of hosts, and not a single server.

A torrent file is usually just a few KBs in size, and contains no actual file data. The torrent file is loaded into a torrent application, like BitTorrent or Deluge, in order to start downloading the actual files.

So to answer your question; a torrent file **cannot** be converted into an ISO file. You need to use a bittorrent application in order to download the actual file, which will (if you've chosen the right torrent) be an ISO. You may also download the ISO directly through HTTP, but note that the download speed will usually be somewhat slower. There may also be no HTTP option available for older versions.