# Top incredibly useful Ubuntu programs

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation

What are the best software in Ubuntu for different applications? I never found any such lists as we can see in the case of Windows. I think that'd be very helpful for new users. May be we can have a list with two or three programs for different applications based on their quality or performance.

Comment: Sorry, but big-list opinion-poll questions are not a good fit to Stack Exchange.

Comment: well..I didn't mean a big list, just for the basic needs to get a better picture for beginners..I'm truly sorry if it does not comply with the rules of this forum.

Comment: Well, it would be better to split off with questions for each individual category, such as [media players](http://askubuntu.com/questions/42532/), [desktop environments](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/), [browsers](http://askubuntu.com/q/44326/158442), [IDEs](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/), etc.

Comment: We already have this kind of question but split into specific types of software. And even those get closed more often than not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic list for a few categories:

- Graphics:

  - Raw editor for fine tuning: Darkroom.
  - Photo editors: Gimp or Krita (I prefer Gimp).
  - Vector drawing: Inkscape.
  - Video editing: Openshot may be a good start, if you are an advanced user, try Natron.
  - 3D modeling: Blender (It has a slow learning curve, but I think that is the best)
- Office:

  - LibreOffice maybe the best solution. However you can find alternatives.
- Internet:

  - Web browsers: Firefox, Chromium or Midori (I prefer Firefox).
  - Torrent manager: Transmission.
  - Download managers: Firefox integrated DM or JDownloader (It has lots of options).
  - Mail clients: Thunderbird or Evolution (I prefer Thunderbird).
- Others:

  - Run Windows software on GNU/Linux: Wine.

This is a small list, but you can find really big lists on Internet. However that are my preferred applications, this is not the absolute truth.

Comment: Kdenlive is great for video editing. I was never able to get Openshot to work reliably.