# Where can I get games for Ubuntu's Unity Engine?

Tags: unity, games, engine

I'm new to Ubuntu, but I installed it because Windows gave me too many virus problems. I heard that Unity is a cross-platform engine, so I can run good graphics games on Linux.

Where I can get a list of good games that run on the Unity game engine? I haven't found any in the software center, nor on [Unity's website](http://unity3d.com/). Can you please point me to a list of good Unity games?

Answer (score 4):

You've got things mixed here.. Unity as in Ubuntu's Unity is a GUI.

> Founded in 2010, the Unity project started by Mark Shuttleworth and Canonical has gone on to deliver a consistent user experience for desktop and netbook users alike. Putting great design at the heart of the project, Unity and its technologies such as Application indicators, System indicators, and Notify OSD, have strived to solve common problems in the Free Software desktop while optimizing the experience for touch, consistency and collaboration.
>
> http://unity.ubuntu.com/

Unity as the game engine

> Unity is an integrated authoring tool for creating 3D video games or other interactive content such as architectural visualizations or real-time 3D animations.
>
> http://unity3d.com/

This are the games that use the engine:

- Among the Sleep
- Battlestar Galactica Online
- Space Paranoids Online
- Cabals:The Card Game
- Family Guy Online
- Fray
- Kerbal Space Program
- Rochard
- Tiger Woods PGA Tour Online
- ***Wasteland 2*** (This one is meant for Linux)
- Slender (video game)
- City of Steam

[Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28game_engine%29#Linux)

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed, I mixed this up. Maybe Ubuntu should rename this. It's confusing when googling it.

Answer (score 0):

The Unity website does have a [list of games made with Unity](http://unity3d.com/gallery/made-with-unity/game-list)

Just to clarify, the [Ubuntu Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/) (the default user interface) is different from the [Unity game engine](http://unity3d.com/) (Unity3D).  This post refers to the game engine.

There are also many other game engines that games for Ubuntu are made in, so the games you play don't have to be Unity based.  **Games made for Ubuntu can be found in the [Ubuntu Software Centre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/department/games/)**

Also, not all games will run on Ubuntu but there are community projects dedicated to allowing Windows applications to run on Ubuntu.

The easiest and most popular method to do so is to use an application called **[PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/)**.  Follow the instructions to install that application, and it will guide you through getting the application running.  *Don't expect applications to run as well as they did on Windows.  There will likely be performance drops in the application as it is trying to simulate another OS while to program is running.*

PlayOnLinux can also run other applications like Microsoft Office 2007 (Not 2010 yet).  If you are feeling brave, it also allows you to add a custom application that is not yet in the database.  This may take some trial and error playing with the settings until it runs well.

Also, see the following question.  It will help:

**[Where can I find websites that list games for Ubuntu? [closed]](https://askubuntu.com/q/39382/72212)**