# How do I install altitude? (.sh file, game)

Tags: games, software-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I run .sh files in Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files-in-terminal)

I've been trying to install the altitude.sh file I got from [altitudegame.com](http://altitudegame.com/download.html).
but I don't know how to install it. And it is not in the Software Center either. 
I found the game [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6586/what-native-games-are-available/7765#7765)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to go through GUI, when you right click on the file and goto permissions tab then you get an option to make the file executable as in the picture.
[image]

and then you have two methods to install the game.

**Method 1:**

Open Terminal.
Go to the directory you have the file.
Type `./filename.sh` and hit Enter.
Or you can type `bash filename.sh`.

**Method 2: (Easiest way)**

Double-click on the file the way you open any other file.
That should install the application by running the script in .sh file.
Follow the prompts (if any) while installation which should look the same as they look in Windows.
That’s it. You are all set.

Hope this quick tip helped you install the application.

Comment: Method 1 works after making the file executable.

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, and first I described how to make it executable.

Comment: This is good if you are not as familiar to a terminal. :)

Answer (score 1):

Htorque told me to type in a terminal when I had the file in my home folder.

```
chmod +x altitude.sh
```

And then type

```
./altitude.sh
```

And now it works great, thanks!

Comment: I prefer this way, I don't like the graphic way too much, sorry.

Comment: This is useful too , and it's as you like and prefer

Comment: Next time just specify your requirements in your original question. If your questions are vague you'll get different answers.

Comment: I know I have some questions that are vague, but is this question vague?