# What are the default games that come with a desktop installation?

Tags: games

Is there a list of the default games for each/any one version of Ubuntu Desktop?

Answer (score 5):

- Mahjongg
- Sudoku
- AisleRiot Solitaire
- FreeCell Solitaire
- Mines

These are the ones my fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS came with.

**Edit**: [Here's an article on some of the games Ubuntu used to ship with.](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2009/11/fewer-games-to-be-included-in-ubuntu-lucid-lynx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are these the only ones ?

Comment: These are the ones listed under the "Games" category, at least. But dozens of other free games are only a click away in the Software Center.

Comment: Ok. I needed only the ones that come with fresh install. Do you know the name of the game in which a particular shaped object has to be moved out of a maze by moving other objects ?

Comment: Do you mean [Sokoban](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban) by any chance?

Comment: Thanks, it looks very similar. Perhaps it's the one. Does it go by the same name in fresh install of Ubuntu?

Comment: On 12.04 at least there's no Sokoban or Sokoban-clone installed by default. Don't know whether previous versions ever came with one.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you're asking which games are currently installed? I'm not sure what is otherwise meant unless you're just curious (in which case, the question in too open-ended *see FAQ*).

**For Ubuntu 12.04**

Use the Ubuntu Software Center, choose installed packages from the top menu, and sort for games by clicking its drop-down menu in the results pane. To install more games, the same as above - but obviously skip the first step and DO NOT click the installed button on top.

**For previous versions with Synaptic Package Manager**

Choose installed from the left-sidebar. In the quick filter box at the top, type "games" and click search. To search for more games, click not-installed from the left-sidebar, and type "games" in the quick filter box at the top.

**A list of native-format games**
A link to another question that probably belongs in the Wiki: [what-native-games-are-available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6586/what-native-games-are-available) as it borders on asking for shopping recommendations.

Comment: No, I meant if there is an official website that lists the default games that come with a fresh install of Ubuntu. I don't have an access to Ubuntu system, hence need a webpage where this information is given. I have edited the question to prevent confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm still confused.  Are you going to install a version of Ubuntu based off of which games come in the installation package?  Because several different packages are available per release version (Xubuntu, etc.) - plus custom packages are available. Also, it's trivial easy to install games through the Ubuntu Software Center in 12.04.

Comment: given your response to a later answer, you were asking "Can someone tell me what the name of a specific game that I once played is?  I know it came included on an official Ubuntu release of 12.04 LTS, and its description is as follows...."

Comment: I refer to Ubuntu Desktop version (not XUbuntu or others). Yes, perhaps I should have worded the question like you suggested; but I thought if there is already a webpage which gives this information that would just as well do. I thought that this (list of games that come with fresh install) will surely be documented somewhere on the internet.

Comment: I'm surprised I couldn't find it either! I thought maybe in a wiki or something...@Glutanimate do you know if those are always the packaged games with each release or do they change?  Because if they change, I'm surprised there isn't some kind of chat or meta conversation about how inclusion is decided that I could have linked to. @user13107 I wasn't trying to be picky, I just was trying to read more into your question and why you were asking it maybe would have helped steer what kind of answer I was trying to give.

Comment: sure, no problem! Perhaps it'd have been more efficient (now that we are not able to search such a page) to go as per your suggestion.

Comment: @Clayton I have no idea as I am fairly new to Ubuntu as well. I found this post, though, that describes some of the games Ubuntu used to ship with and why they were included: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2009/11/fewer-games-to-be-included-in-ubuntu-lucid-lynx