# What are the alternatives to Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, backup

Since canonical is [shutting down](http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/) Ubuntu One, what are the possible alternatives?

I currently use Ubuntu One as a backup service for my Documents folder and various other folders I deem important. Of course I have backups on an external hard drive as well, but nevertheless, I find Ubuntu One to be very useful. What I'm especially looking for is a cloud service that does not need a special folder (such as a dropbox or google drive folder); something that is able to integrate into my own file system and syncs just any folder I want to.

I am aware that this question is rather subjective, but I do guess many people who have used Ubuntu One are now in the dark.

Comment: I use [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) to sync between my PCs. Often at a continent of distance... you never know, meteorites... It is highly configurable (although you probably will need to edit the conf file by hand). Available in standard ubuntu repository. It is multiplatform, safe and fast, and can be scripted.

Comment: Seems to me that an rsync cronjob to a VPS might be easier to setup?

Comment: Maybe; but the basic usage of Unison (using unison-gtk graphic interface) is a breeze and you have a nice interface to solve conflicts when they arise. YMMV... About shells around `rsync`, I was starting to play with [Back in Time](http://backintime.le-web.org/) , seemed interesting... let it alone due to lack of time.

Comment: Hmm.. missed the part about the GUI around unison. Nice! I've used back in time when I was a "newbie" to CLI stuff. Found it's exceptionally, well... SLOW compared to just typing some rsync commands. Dunno why.

Comment: could anyone posting please include a link to software center if possible or to the site where to find the download? That will save a lot of people time ;)

Comment: So this was NOT an April Fools Joke?

Comment: If you have access to an ssh server (say, belonging to the corporate you work for), you can use rsync.

Comment: Try OneDrive (New name for Skydrive) - I THINK it is web only on Ubuntu, but on Windows and Android it works quite well, and it also integrates really well with outlook, unlike Dropbox, is that is who you use your email for

Comment: Well he does state that he wants something which can synchronize any user-specified folder (rather than a specific folder)... My understanding is that most "cloud" storage systems don't support this - so why is this question "on hold"?

Comment: Asking for a list of alternatives to a specific service is not too subjective, nor too broad. There should also be many questions like this expected over the next few days.

Comment: Where is the broadness of this question? This is a pretty objective problem affecting millions of users and you can pretty much expect a deluge of questions the following weeks. I myself ended up in this thread when preparing to file a similar question.

Comment: @dobey as long as any and every answer is valid, it's too broad.

Comment: If anyone wants something check http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2928/alternative-to-ubuntu-one-client-and-service-that-can-run-automated-backups

Comment: @Braiam No, it isn't. Otherwise all the other similar questions on AskUbuntu that have been protected, like https://askubuntu.com/questions/6586/what-native-games-are-available , need to be closed as "Too Broad" as well.

Comment: @dobey if it wasn't Locked, I would have followed the [meta Q](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/503/169736) and close it, as the Community have done with [other several Q's](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=closed%3A1+score%3A20+duplicate%3A0).

Comment: See also: [Dear Ubuntu One Users: What SpiderOak Can Do For You](https://spideroak.com/blog/20140402145558-dear-ubuntu-one-users-spideroak-can)

Comment: I'd really like to allow this, I really would, but it is really just quite too broad. There is a [discourse thread](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/what-are-your-plans-to-replace-ubuntu-one-and-why/1598) on the topic however. @dobey If you see any more very broad questions like that feel free to flag them for closure. Also, protection is only to stop new users from posting non answers in the answer section, nothing else ;)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The following is a list of the cloud services similar to Ubuntu One that work in Ubuntu (Can be installed with a .DEB file) and may provide support for the Unity Systray:

## Dropbox [image]

**Website** - https://www.dropbox.com/
**Starting Free Space** - 2 GB
**Bonus Space** - 25 GB to 50 GB when used on an Smartphone
**Characteristics** - Sync Files/Folders between devices.
**Unity SysTray Support**- YES
**Open Source** - NO

## InSync [image]

**Website** - https://www.insynchq.com/
**Characteristics** - Sync Files/Folders with Google Drive. Extensive Sharing properties. 15 Day Trial.
**Unity SysTray Support** - YES
**Open Source** - NO

## OwnCloud [image]

**Website** - http://owncloud.org/
**Characteristics** - Sync Files/Folders between Devices on your "Own Cloud".
**Support** - http://owncloud.org/providers/
**Unity SysTray Support** - YES
**Open Source** - YES ([GitHub](https://github.com/owncloud))

## SpiderOak [image]

**Website** - https://spideroak.com/
**Starting Free Space** - 2 GB
**Characteristics** - Sync Files/Folders between devices. Advanced GUI System & File History
**Unity SysTray Support** - YES
**Open Source** - NO

## Wuala [image]

**Website** - http://www.wuala.com/
**Starting Free Space** - 0 GB  Paid Only
**Characteristics** - Sync Files/Folders. GUI System and an easy way to manage files across devices.
**Unity SysTray Support** - YES
**Open Source** - NO

## Tonido  [image]

**Website** - http://www.tonido.com/
**Starting Free Space** - 2 GB
**Characteristics** - Sync Files/Folders between computers.
**Unity SysTray Support** - YES
**Open Source** - NO

## TeamDrive [image]

**Website** - http://www.teamdrive.com/
**Starting Free Space** - 2 GB
**Characteristics** - Sync Files/Folders between computers. File Collaboration (Multi User Support)
**Bonus Space** - Up to 10 GB by inviting others.
**Unity SysTray Support** - YES
**Open Source** - NO

## SeaFile [image]

**Website** - http://seafile.com/en/home/
**Starting Free Space** - 1 GB
**Characteristics** - Sync Files/Folders between computers.
**Unity SysTray Support** - YES
**Open Source** - YES ([GitHub](https://github.com/haiwen/seafile))

## Syncany [image]

**Website** - http://www.syncany.org/
**Starting Free Space** - Depends on which cloud service you use
**Characteristics** - Sync Files/Folders between computers. Can use Picasa, RackSpace, Amazon, Google, Windows Share and even WebDAV as a repository. Nautilus integration. Advanced GUI. Can integrate with other Cloud Services. Very flexible.
**Unity SysTray Support** - YES
**Open Source** - YES ([GitHub](https://github.com/binwiederhier/syncany))

## Copy (Barracuda) [image]

**Website** - https://www.copy.com/home/
**Starting Free Space** - 15 GB
**Characteristics** - Up to 5 Devices Synced, 5 GB+ for every invite, Can personalized space provided for a single user. Nautilus integration. Advanced GUI. Can integrate with other Cloud Services. Very flexible. Supports soft symlinks.
**Unity SysTray Support** - YES
**Open Source** - NO

### Others that may be used (Open Source):

[image] **OwnDrive** - https://owndrive.com/

- Unified Access to multiple Cloud Services
- 1 GB Free Space

[image] **SparkleShare** - http://sparkleshare.org/

- Open Source ([GitHub](https://github.com/hbons/SparkleShare))
- Version Control & Privacy

### Others that may be used (Closed Source):

[image] **Asus Web Storage** - https://www.asuswebstorage.com/navigate/

- 5 GB free space
- More free space if you use ASUS Devices

[image] **SugarSync** - https://www.sugarsync.com/

- 30 Day Trial
- 60 GB Starting Size (Not free)

[image] **BitTorrent Sync** - http://www.bittorrent.com/sync/downloads

- Offer API to Developers
- Direct Transfer between Devices

[image] **BitCasa** - https://www.bitcasa.com/

- 5 GB (Upto 20 GB via inviting others) Free Space
- Up to 3 Clients

[image] **GoAruna** - http://goaruna.com/

- 2 GB Free Space
- Works on many devices

In my case I stick with Dropbox and InSync. Tried SpiderOak and there was a lack of User-Friendliness that I did not use it after a week. InSync is pretty cool (Saves me a lot of time). Lastly Syncany has pretty cool options to connect to other cloud services and even create your own for privacy.

Comment: This InSync thing looks exactly like I'm looking for!

Comment: +1 for SpiderOak. I agree that it is less user-friendly than the others, but its major advantage is privacy. Nobody but you has access to the files you store, SpiderOak doesn't store copies of your encryption keys like most providers do.

Comment: It would be nice if you could expand this answer by adding in which country(ies) these companies store the data.

Comment: Following up on my own comment earlier: European users might want to go with [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org) and choose among a [myriad of supported service providers hosted in Europe](http://owncloud.org/providers/).

Comment: Thanks Luis for the great answer! If I may suggest an improvement: add the information of which ones are open source and which aren't.

Comment: Another major advantage of SpiderOak is historic versions of files. You always have all historic versions of the files that you work on, unlike in Dropbox (where these are available for 30 days only).

Comment: Is there a software that automatically signs up for all the cloud storage services and we can use the free storage 2Gb+ for all?

Comment: After this answer there is no sync app left on the planet internet @LuisAlvarado ... Very good answer.

Comment: Just want to add that one can use google drive with grive tools..

Comment: OwnCloud client is well supported in Ubuntu. I lease a server so I use one of my domains as the server also supports OwnCloud via cPanel.

Comment: Wuala offers no free storage to new users anymore: 
https://support.wuala.com/2014/06/shifting-to-paid-only-service/

Comment: Copy did not get enough credit here. I think it is the best choice for Linux users. Because, first, it has an app that runs in Linux, that makes syncing easy, secondly, you get 15GB free and en extra 5GB (up to extra 15GB) for every new user that you referred to this service, and thirdly, it SUPPORTS SYMLINKS!!! This means that you put in your synced folder symlinks to anywhere you want and copy regards them as a folder.

Comment: @yaron160 thanks for the information just added the new changes of Copy, including the unity integration and symlink support.

Comment: insync is not free even for linux. it has a trial version.

Answer (score 2):

One of my favorite services that no one is listing is BitTorrent Sync. They offer UNLIMITED transfer and storage space; it works just like Dropbox.

The ONLY downside is that it is indeed BitTorrent; one computer has to be on with the files. I just let it run on my laptop. It's multiplatform, and its incredibly sharable.

Ther's also Dropbox, which I highly recommend.

Answer (score 1):

I use Google Drive with Insync. I think Insync is the most decent cloud service client for Ubuntu, as you can leave your files where they are, because Insync can follow symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

OneMediaHub (Funambol) is a good one. It's supported by large amounts of different hardware and operating systems. I sync my Android device with Google, Evolution, my Nokia N8, etc. It's really quite good. It's open source as well, so you can run it yourself if you want to.

It supports notes, contacts, calendar, todo, pictures, video, music and other files.