# How can I install ubuntu one after upgrading to ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-one, 14.04, software-installation

I upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 without realizing that the ubuntu one package was going to be removed (my fault). I know the ubuntu one service is being discontinued but I'd like to keep on using it at least until I have time to look for something else to replace it. Is there a way to install ubuntu one again on ubuntu 14.04?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you have a look at _Sparkleshare_ ?

Comment: @dobey: I think my question is not clear, my interest is not in how to recover the files but in how to keep my files synced with ubuntu one after upgrading.

Comment: @andres On June 1, you won't be able to connect to the server with the client on Ubuntu anyway. You need to download the files from the service, and discontinue use of the client, sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the `ubuntuone-client`, nor the `ubuntuone-control-panel` packages are available for Ubuntu 14.04 from the repositories. Considering how close we are to the shut down of the service you should take this opportunity to [find an alternative](https://askubuntu.com/q/442430/177437) right away.