# Moving from Windows 8.1 to Ubuntu - what can I do to replace OneDrive?

Tags: windows-8, mint

That's it - I got tired from the constant problems on and about Windows I'm having. Network issues, performance issues, compatibility issues... But I'll seriously miss OneDrive integration (all my files are there). There is some kind of app that can sync with it? And what is the easiest way to install JDK? Through PPAs? Note that I have no plans to keep Windows, I'll just replace the d*mn thing with Ubuntu (maybe Mint).

Comment: Here is the list of [Ubuntu One alternatives](http://askubuntu.com/questions/442430/what-are-the-alternatives-to-ubuntu-one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options, I switch from onedrive to google drive, and have been loving it.

However, Google drive doesn't quite mesh with linux just yet. The website says:

```
 "Running Linux? Stay tuned - Drive for Linux isn't ready just yet."
```

Dropbox supports linux and works pretty much like OneDrive and Google drive. Just transfer your files over!

Hope this helps! Welcome to Linux!

Comment: the biggest problem about moving from OneDrive to Dropbox is that my files won't fit. Dropbox has 2Gb for free while on OneDrive I have 25Gb. Of course I'm not using it all, I think I'm hitting 25% of it, but I can't make 6Gb fit into 2Gb. I also can't pay for storage. But I'll look after it.

Comment: It is possible to use Google Drive with `google-drive-ocamlfuse`.

Comment: If you're looking for space, copy.com has 15GB to start with and 5GB extra for anybody else you sign up... so add 2 others and you have your 25GB (there's no limit, add 100 and you have 500GB extra!). There is a client for Linux but you'll need some fix to get the display in unity working correctly. It syncs properly though and you can always change configuration via the web. It also has clients for Android, iOS, Windows and Mac

Comment: now that is a interesting alternative. I'll look for it, thanks!