# Roguelike platformers available on ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, games

Are there any rogue-like side scrolling platformers available on ubuntu?

Comment: Rogue legacy on steam runs on linux as well

Comment: @noleti; would you mind posting that as an answer, perhaps with a screenshot? I would like to upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays, Good old Games (gog.com) and Steam (Steampowered.com) are very good sources for games on Linux. Regarding rogue-like sidescrollers, both have *[Rogue Legacy](http://store.steampowered.com/app/241600/)*. Steam also has *99 Levels To Hell*, which also looks like a rogue-like sidescroller.

**Step-by-step instructions for Rogue Legacy on Steam**

1. [How to install steam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1784/how-can-i-install-steam).
2. Buy the game using the web interface.
3. The game will then show in your library.
4. Click install, click throught the following screens and it will start downloading.
5. Enjoy! It worked straight out of the box on my machine.

[image: RL running in windowed mode on Xubuntu]

Answer (score 3):

The [LGDB](http://www.lgdb.org/page/about) (Linux Game Database) is a very comprehensive site for Native linux games:

> This is a Linux Game Database, primarily for native Linux games that
>   are beyond the planing stage and have released more than tech demos,
>   ether as source code or binary files. The information about a game is
>   usually taken from the game site. The games are carefully categorized
>   and presented with screenshots and videos. The submission guidelines
>   explain what kind of Linux games are in the database.
>
> You can browse the database whilst applying a lot of filters to tweak
>   the output. This site uses two methods to rank games:
>
> - user votes and
> - popularity
>
> the popularity is the sum of visits for the past three days.

And there is a section on  [Roguelike games:
[image]](http://www.lgdb.org/category/subgenre/roguelike) . Other alternatives may be listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/7174/178596).

You may also be able to run [Rogue Legacy in Wine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124579/running-rogue-legacy-on-linux). See also, the [AppDB entry](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28629).

Comment: Unfortunately, no side scrolling roguelikes are listed.

Comment: Some older Windows games can run well under Wine, that may work as a alternative.

Comment: Could you offer a specific suggestion of a sidescrolling platformer rogue like game that works well under wine?

Answer (score 2):

If you install bsdgames-nonfree, there is a very good version of rogue named, oddly enough, rogue.

```
sudo apt-get install bsdgames-nonfree
```

You might also be interested in the regular bsdgames

```
sudo apt-get install bsdgames
```

[BSD Games Wikipedia page](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/BSD_games)

Comment: My question was in regards to sidescrolling platformer roguelike games, not roguelike games in general. Nothing of what you linked helps answer my inquiry. If you could provide an actual example, I will reverse my downvote.