# Some advice regarding software

Tags: software-recommendation

Hey guys i wanted to ask if there will be any inconvenience if I use Linux .

The problem is my teacher has recommended me

1.) G++ compiler
2.) Notepad ++
3.) MS Visual Studio 2012

What are the alternatives or I will have to purchase Windows .
I am currently using Linux Mint 17 and loving it. Plus really limited on resources because I am a computer science student .

Secondary question

Can you tell me where to get some free games ?

Comment: g++ is easy to obtain in Linux, notepad is a simple text editor, and easily replaced.  MS Visual Studio is a proprietary product of Microsoft, needs to be purchased, and runs only under Windows.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Notepad++ is hard to replace. Notepad is easily replaced.

Comment: You won't need Notepad++ *and* Visual Studio – you would be using either one or the other, depending on whether you enjoy the benefits of using an IDE or whether you dislike the overhead. VS is a great IDE, but it's in no way necessary to do C++ development.

Comment: @sebastian_k: You don't know what kind of lessons the school planned. They suggest this software for a reason and they probably going to use it in colleges. In my school we learned to program initially in Notepad++ (because it was quick and doesn't fix your errors for you) and learned VS after that because it's pretty much an industry standard.

Comment: @Gladen that's a good point, you're probably right. Ali, your school likely has a deal with Microsoft (MSDN Academic Alliance, Dreamspark or similar) that allows students to get licenses for Windows and VS for free. If your teacher insists on you using MS software, you may just have to suck it up for a year.

Comment: This question is a little too open ended for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `g++` compiler runs better on Linux than it ever does on Windows. Search for `g++` in the Software Centre or:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential
   ```
2. The default text editor, `gedit`, is a couple of rungs above Notepad and a few rungs below Notepad++. However, most people never use the full feature-set of Notepad++ and Gedit should be enough for them. If not, try something like `vim`, `emacs` or Sublime Editor. [What developer text editors are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/10998/158442)
3. [What IDEs are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu)

Secondary: [What native games are available?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6586/158442) (some are paid, but some are free)

Answer (score 0):

If you're in college it's probably adviced to use the software that is suggested by your teachers because the lessons are based on those. You can easily set up a virtual machine with Windows on your machine however. Many institutes provide free versions of Windows to their students, but you will have to consult your school about that.

Anyway, if you're determined to go entirely Ubuntu, you can do so. G++ is available on Ubuntu, Gedit can be a notepad++ replacement and MS Visual Studio can be replaced by Eclipse or NetBeans (for C/C++) or MonoDevelop (for C#)

Comment: Thank you guys.What I did was installed netbeans for my laptop and installed win 7 in my PC. By the way great support !!!